# Logoff does not restrict file access to users (Django)

Tags: django, authentication, browser-cache

I have created a Django app and incorporated in one of the app's page this [D3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/). This example gets the data from the file `data.tsv` which is stored in my server. Say the path to the `data.tsv` file is `PATH`.

Now in order to prevent access to `http://localhost:8000/PATH` from users other that those who are registered and use my django app I have changed with `chmod` the privileges of others in a root folder to PATH so they can nor read nor execute or write.

My problem is that when a user who was logged in decides to logout
the tab that was using is able to access `http://localhost:8000/PATH`
as if something is cached in the users browser. If for example I reset the browser then the `http://localhost:8000/PATH` is not accessible.

Do you have any ideas on how I can prevent this? Thank you very much